# Some references do not show in my bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

In my .bib archive I have other references, but when compiling only shows those that I have reference them in my .tex document.

How could I make that those that I dont reference in my .tex document shows at the end of my document in my bibliography? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command with every reference you want to add to your bibliography:

`\nocite{Einstein1905}`